# Getting unexpected large integer

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm following an example to count how many times a word occurs in given input. Here is my code:

```
string word, the_word;
int count(0);
vector<string> sentence;
auto it = sentence.begin();
cout << "Enter some words. Ctrl+z to end." << endl;
while (cin >> word)
    sentence.push_back(word);

the_word = *sentence.begin();
cout << the_word << endl;
while(it != sentence.end()) {
    if(*sentence.begin() == the_word)
        ++count;
    ++it;
}
cout << count << endl;
```

The input I'm giving is "how now now now brown cow cow". I expect `count` to be 3, but instead I get an integer in the 2 millions. What am I missing?

Comment: You're reinventing `std::count`, and should initialize the vector with iterators.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidated iterator

```
auto it = sentence.begin()
```

You are assigning `it` before inserting values. Move this line after input loop.

```
+-- auto it = sentence.begin();
|   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
|    
|   while (cin >> word)
|       sentence.push_back(word);
|
+--> // Move it here.


    if(*sentence.begin() == the_word)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // Change to *it
```

Also you can use [`std::count`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count) instead:

```
cout << "Enter some words. Ctrl+z to end." << endl;

vector<string> v((istream_iterator<string>(cin)),istream_iterator<string>());

int c = v.size()? count(v.begin(), v.end(), v.front()) : 0;
```